# css toggleClass in jquery?

Tags: jquery, css, toggleclass

i want to toggle between designs

```
/* Heart sign */
.fav {
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: #0099CC;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url(../images/heart-icons.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
}

fav:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    background: url(../images/heart-icons.png) no-repeat 4px -13px #EDEDED;
}
```

jquery:

```
$('.fav').live('click', function(e){

    $(this).toggleClass('fav:hover');

    });
```

but this is not working!!! any help please

Comment: i was thinking to give the fav:hover another name so jquery knows, but then i might lose the hover effect intially, but what i want is when the user clicks on the .fav is to take the hover state, if this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you'll probably have to have a duplicate. Keep the hover and then add another class which gives the same style as :hover, then toggle that class.

God bless!

Comment: You don't need to duplicate. You can just add another class name to .fav:hover

Answer (score 4):

Solution without Javascript:

```
.fav:hover, .fav:active {
    ...
}
```

Also note that I fixed `.fav`.

Comment: Are they using it on a link? getaway doesn't say and I don't think this is cross browser compatible for elements other than links.

Answer (score 3):

Like Trinidad said, you'll have to do a duplicate, but no need to copy paste. Just do this:

```
/* Heart sign */
.fav {
    margin-left: 0px;
    color: #0099CC;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 4px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: url(../images/heart-icons.png) no-repeat 4px 4px;
}

.fav:hover,
.fav-clicked {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-right: -1px;
    background-color: #EDEDED;
    border: 1px solid #999999;
    background: url(../images/heart-icons.png) no-repeat 4px -13px #EDEDED;
}
```

then you can set it in jquery:

```
$('.fav').live( 'click', function() {
   $(this).toggleClass('.fav-clicked');
})
```

(just think of a more semantic name for clicked)

This in turn will make your div(or whatever html element with fav) look like this:

```
<div class="fav"> <-- before clicking
```

*click*

```
<div class="fav fav-clicked">
```

*click*

```
<div class="fav">
```

If you need to do some ajax requests on your fav-clicked items, just access your fav-clicked items by:

```
$('.fav-clicked')
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, how can i also tell which toggle has been used, so then i can send each action to another ajax request if you know what i mean!

Comment: Well, that's just the way someone who really knows CSS would do it. I'm still on the copy-past age. =P

Comment: im not sure what you mean though, but the toggleclass method adds the "fav-clicked" class to your div with the "fav" class(if it doesn't have it) or removes the fav-clicked if fav already has it. ill update my answer to be more clear

Answer (score 3):

First of all you have a mistake in your CSS. `fav:hover` should be `.fav:hover` (note the period).

Second, I think don't think you can do it exactly as you have it. Instead you can change your CSS to:

```
.fav:hover, .fav_hover {
```

And then change your JS to:

```
 $(this).toggleClass('fav_hover');
```

I don't think you can tell jQuery to use a hover pseudo class.